# new array created with new Array(+5)

Tags: javascript

The title says it all.

I've just seen someone creating a new array as such:

```
var container = new Array(+max);
```

Where `max` was an integer. I've tested and it works. I've also tested without the `+` symbol and it also works, so why is it there? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Doesn't make much sense, unless `max` is a string like `+'5' === 5`

Comment: That was exactly the case and I realized it myself just 10 seconds after asking this question. I'll answer to my own question, maybe someone will encounter the same and take longer to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question, found solution seconds later, couldn't find it on stackoverflow, leaving it for the future.

In some cases, the `max` might be a string, and thus adding the `+` mutates it into a number if the object(string) is composed only of numbers. `parseInt(max)` would yield the same result.